# EditMode in TableEdit for PrimeNG is not functioning

Tags: angular, user-interface, primeng

I wanted to able to edit existing remarks in the '' table, The 'pInputTextArea' is not accepting any new entries if I try to edit with new entries on the existing entries. I was not able to select and remove the data that has been pre-existing in the 'pInputTextArea' text holder.

```
  <p-panel header="List of Maintenance Days " [collapsed]="createMaintanencePanelNextCollapsed" [toggleable]="true"
        (click)="viewMaintenanceDays()">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row" style="height: 320px;">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                     <!-- @HEma Edit 
                   -->
              <p-table [columns]="maintanenceDaysColumn" [value]="maintanenceDayModel" selectionMode="multiple" editMode="row"
                scrollHeight="200px" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true" [(selection)]="selectedMaintenanceDay" dataKey="id"
                [tableStyle]="{'table-layout':'auto'}" >
                <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                  <tr>
                      <th style="width: 3em">
                          <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                      </th>
                    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" style="text-align: center">
                      {{col.header}}
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center"> 
                        User Actions
                      </th>
                  </tr>

                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-ri="rowIndex" let-editing="editing">
                    <tr [pEditableRow]="rowData" >
                        <td>
                            <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
                        </td>

                        <td class="" >
                            {{rowData.id}}
                        </td>
                        <td class=".ng-invalid.ng-dirty"style="min-width: 100px">
                            {{rowData.maintainceDates}}
                        </td>
                        <td   >
                          <p-cellEditor>
                              <ng-template pTemplate="input" >
                                  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.remarks" style="width: 100%"
                                   class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched">
                              </ng-template>
                              <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                  {{rowData.remarks}}
                              </ng-template>
                          </p-cellEditor>
                              </td>
                      <td style="text-align:center; min-width: 180px; " >
                          <button *ngIf="!editing" pButton type="button" pInitEditableRow icon="fa fa-pencil-square-o"  label="Edit" 
                          class="ui-button-info" (click)="onRowEditInit(rowData)"></button>
                          <button *ngIf="editing" pButton type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="fa fa-check-square-o" label="Save" 
                          class="ui-button-success" style="margin-right: .5em" (click)="onRowEditSave(rowData)"></button>
                          <button *ngIf="editing" pButton type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon=" fa fa-times" label="Cancel" 
                           class="ui-button-danger" (click)="onRowEditCancel(rowData, ri)"></button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </ng-template> 
     </p-table>
              <button [hidden]="selectedMaintenanceDay == undefined || !selectedMaintenanceDay.length" pButton type="button"
                class="ui-button-primary" (click)="delMaintanenceDays()" icon="fa fa-trash" label="Delete" iconPos="left"
                style="height: 28px; margin-top: 8px;"></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </p-panel>
```

## Expected Results

- it should allow the to edit. it's not even provide the blinking option to edit.

## Error_Msg

- no error message shown in console/

## Version : Angular & Node.js

Angular CLI: 8.1.1
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

### Package                      Version

- List item
- @angular-devkit/architect    0.801.1
- @angular-devkit/core         8.1.1
- @angular-devkit/schematics   8.1.1
- @schematics/angular          8.1.1
- @schematics/update           0.801.1
- rxjs                         6.4.0

## version_primeng

"primeflex": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.1.0-rc.1",

## version os

Windows 10* 64-bit